# Set Powerpoint presentation format to 16:9

Tags: aspose, aspose-slides

How can I create a Powerpoint document with presentation format 16:9 in Aspose.Powerpoint? 4:3 seems to be default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a PowerPoint file with presentation format 16:9 by using the code below:

```
        Presentation pres = new Presentation();
        pres.SlideSize.Type = SlideSizeType.OnScreen16x9;
        pres.Save(@"D:\16_9.pptx", Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.